# SVPWM Zero Vector Braking?

Tags: motor-controller

I have some trouble in understandy Space Vector PWM (SVPWM) with the zero vector. To modulate the amplitude of the vector, the zero vector (000) or (111) is applied for a certain time. This means, that the motor phases are shorted. This should lead to braking, or am I wrong? And if so, this would be very inefficient, right? What am I missing here?

**Edit:** Here is an example of SVPWM, where the zero vector is applied for a certain time. With a 3 phase-inverter, this means all low-side mosfets (or all high side mosfets) are conducting, which means all phases are shorted together. I understand that this zero vector needs to be applied to modulate the current amplitude, but I don't understand if this state really means braking for the motor and if so, then this should waste a lot of energy, right?

[image]

It is also good to see in the following picture, where all phases are sometimes connected together through the high or the low side:

[image]

Comment: ? A lot more details !  The drivers must also be much lower R than the motor and can return energy to the bus or bypass to brake shunt or  simply short motor winding to brake fastest.

Comment: But recuperation is not performed when all the phases are shorted, right?

Comment: not possible unless redirection to Vbat but AC power  source may not need recovered energy

Comment: Yes, so if I apply this zero vector, I simply short the motor, right? So let's say I run a motor with field oriented control with the quadrature current Iq=1A, then I choose Iq=0A as reference value, would this simply short the motor?

Comment: not sure on  your terminology , in practise , 0A means no shunt current applied ? and/ or received ?? or coasting open circuit.. keep reading

Comment: So basically 0A means for the SVPWM part, that always the zero vector is applied, which means half of the time the high side is open, and the other half of the time the low side is open. So this state leads to a short of the motor phases, but If I apply this state at high spead, the whole energy will be dissipated in the motor windings, right?

Comment: If high or low side switches shunt a winding **yes*.  In some case, they do this on Wind Turbines on 1 phase only to slow down the turbine and get in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero vector does not cause braking ... Initially.

The zero volt vector within SVM/SVPWM exists as a realisable state to synthesis the require voltage vector on a sector by sector basis. Whether 000 or 111 is chosen is an implementation concern.

So... Imagine the stator has current flowing. What is going to happen when all the switches are opened? The current is going to freewheel via the FWD and via the DClink - a negative volt loop. This causes the current to decay relatively fast

What is going to happen if you turn on all UPPER or all LOWER switches? Is the current going to rapidly decay to zero and "brake" the rotor? No... It does nothing to actively decelerate the rotor (it will due to mechanical loading) , in fact because it creates a "zero volt loop" the current decays alot slower than if the classic negative volt loop is used (that which is used via SPWM). Likewise this is used for one PWM period before the next state in the SVPWM is used. 
This is equally used in soft-swiching of SR drives as it minimises current ripple due to the zero volt loop

So why is such a scheme referred to as "braking"? If you were to stay in this state rather than switching in and out of this state, the current in the stator will decay, the rate dependant on the RL time constant. Once this has occured you are now in a "braking" state as the changing magnetic field of the rotor-stator interaction induces a voltage which is now shorted out via the inverter. This permits a current to flow that will oppose the rotational force -> braking.

So in summary it depends on how long you are in this state, a very valid and useful state to motor-drives.